# Разработка Custom Gutenberg Блоков, активируемые через разрабатываемый шаблон (theme)

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg

Последние годы часто использовал ACF при разработке сайтов, чтобы дать заказчику возможность редактировать информацию. Иногда приходилось делать виджеты, которые активируются через разрабатываемую тему, обычно использовались они где-то в сайдбаре, где заказчик могу дополнять его дополнительными настраиваемыми блоками меню.

Уже на протяжении двух лет постепенно развивают gutenberg-редактор и очень интересной фичей является возможность внедрять свои кастомные блоки.

Вопрос в чем: как можно активировать эти блоки через разрабатываемую тему? Я знаю, что виджеты можно активировать через тему, а вот для gutenberg-блоков такого не нашел. Или активация gutenberg-блоков производится строго через плагины?

В общем, поделитесь, пожалуйста, вашим опытом. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Да вообще без разницы, где что-то активировать - в тем, плагине или mu-plugin. Важен хук, не то место, откуда он вызван.

Comment: В этом топике я имею в виду про уменьшении зависимости от ACF плагина. При разработке корпоративных сайтов часто сборка шаблона используется из проекта в проект, даже некоторые решения так же могут переиспользоваться. Но про mu-плагины спасибо, почитаю.

Answer (score 0):

Поискал информацию, вроде бы более менее разобрался. В редакторе есть разделение^ блоки и паттерны. Как я понял, мне конкретно нужны были паттерны, не знаю, чем они принципиально отличаются от блоков, но да ладно.

В течении 2-3 недель постараюсь расписать про свой опыт.

Мне помог код на шаге 4, [ссылка на статью](https://misha.agency/gutenberg/patterny.html).

Добавляется следующий код в functions.php в файлах темы:

```php
add_action( 'init', 'truemisha_register_block_pattern', 25 );
 
function truemisha_register_block_pattern() {
 
    if ( class_exists( 'WP_Block_Patterns_Registry' ) ) {
 
        register_block_pattern(
            'truemisha/hero-pattern',
            array(
                'title'       => 'Мишин паттерн',
                'description' => 'Этот паттерн позволяет вам вставить несколько блоков и кнопку с предопределённым текстом.',
                'content'     => "<!-- wp:group {\"align\":\"full\",\"backgroundColor\":\"black\"} -->\n<div class=\"wp-block-group alignfull has-black-background-color has-background\"><div class=\"wp-block-group__inner-container\"><!-- wp:spacer -->\n<div style=\"height:100px\" aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"wp-block-spacer\"></div>\n<!-- /wp:spacer -->\n\n<!-- wp:heading -->\n<h2>Паттерны Gutenberg</h2>\n<!-- /wp:heading -->\n\n<!-- wp:paragraph -->\n<p>Это пример использования паттерна в Gutenberg. Сначала мы настраиваем блоки в редакторе.</p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->\n\n<!-- wp:buttons -->\n<div class=\"wp-block-buttons\"><!-- wp:button {\"textColor\":\"white\",\"className\":\"is-style-outline\"} -->\n<div class=\"wp-block-button is-style-outline\"><a class=\"wp-block-button__link has-white-color has-text-color\">Использовать паттерны</a></div>\n<!-- /wp:button --></div>\n<!-- /wp:buttons -->\n\n<!-- wp:spacer -->\n<div style=\"height:100px\" aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"wp-block-spacer\"></div>\n<!-- /wp:spacer --></div></div>\n<!-- /wp:group -->",
                'categories'  => array( 'header' ),
            )
        );
 
    }
 
}
```